# Ubuntu localhost: Not found

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache-http-server, localhost

I have updated my Ubuntu 13.10 to 14.04, so I have a newer version now.

But I spotted that after the update I experience a 404 error while trying to access my `http://localhost/`

After a complete reinstalling apache and all the related services, it still shows me a 404 error.

By the way, I have added `ServerName localhost` to httpd.conf, so no result, as well as in my hosts file there is a line `127.0.0.1 localhost`.

After trying to `sudo service apache2 restart` I have had an error like `Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1.`, but fixed it successfully.

I am able to access `http://localhost/` via the browser, but it shows me `Index of /` and then empty. But when trying to access any subfolder in my `/var/www/`, like `http://localhost/test1`, it gives me a 404.

Is there any way of fixing it? Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure your Apache's DocumentRoot is set to `/var/www/`?

Comment: That's what I have in my config: http://pastebin.com/ZGFzhZHt

Comment: Oh. Just changed my `etc/apache2/sites-available` config's document root. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take a look at the configuration files at `/etc/apache2/sites-available/`.  By default, there is only one file under the directory named `default` unless you set up other virtual hosts.

The first line of the file is probably like `<VirtualHost *:80>`, meaning that this virtual host listen on port 80 of all IPs available (including localhost for your case).

Look into the file for a block of `<Directory /var/www/>`.  This block of code tells Apache to take into account `/var/www`.  If you don't have this block, Apache simply doesn't know to look into `/var/www` and of course ignoring `/var/www/test1`, in turn giving you a 404 error.  You will need to add in such block accordingly.

You need to give appropriate permission for `/var/www/test1` (at least, read permission, plus execute permission as well if you would like others to list folder contents) to apache (user `www-data` by default).